# CDialog to CView

Tags: mfc, cdialog, cview

So I've an `MFC` based application, which is primarily derived from `CDialog`, with some controls etc.

For certain reasons, it needs to be hosted in another application, using a container class, which is based on `CView`.

So there has to be some way...of hosting this thing, made using `CDialog`, inside a container class, which expects the thing as a `CView`.

The container class is closed to me. It will expect a `CView`, but I can modify the dialog based application.

Is there an easy way to migrate over from `CDialog` based to `CView` based, and what would I need to look at, please. I'm not very skilled with MFC, and the question might sound vague, but it's what I have.

Any help would be appreciated...Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at CFormView class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a CFormView. That is a view supporting dialog resource templates.

The problematic code is loading and commiting the data into and from the CFormView. Views are usually controlled by a CDocument, that calls UpdateAllViews with some hints.

Your dialog functions for OnOK, OnCancel and OnInitDalog must be changed to fit into the Doc/View architecture.

- Move the OnInitDialog code into OnInitialUpdate, but be aware that in an SDI application OnInitialUpdate might be called more than once.
- OnOK and OnCancel must be solved by some calls and functions from the document.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Could you throw more light on the second point please? I didn't quite understand that.

Comment: Create an application with the wizard and a CFromView... may be this will clarify things. Otherwise please ask for specific details. I don't know what to explain in more detail.